# How to create a user via GUI in SQL server 2008 R2 with read only access on specific databases?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am a newbie in SQL server 2008 and slowly learning it. Today I got a task of creating a user with read only access for a specific database in a server. So what should I specify under the tab- 
Server Roles
User Mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In user mappings, simply select the database in question, and choose "DB_Datareader", this should allow the user to read from the database, while nothing else. Considering you probably have no other security set up for this user, this will be the simplest / fastest way.

If you want to have a better idea as to what the role does, try reading: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188629(v=sql.90).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188629%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Comment: No problem, make sure you mark as answer if you have no further questions / remarks ;)